# How to check if there is data saved in DataStore in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

This is my `UserManager.kt` Class which has a function to save and map data but how do create a function which tells me that datastore has user or not?

```
    class UserManager(context: Context) {

    private val dataStore = context.createDataStore(name = "user_prefs")

    companion object {
        val USER_NAME_KEY = preferencesKey<String>("USER_NAME")
        val USER_NUMBER_KEY = preferencesKey<Int>("USER_NUMBER")
    }

    suspend fun storeUser(number: Int, name: String) {
        dataStore.edit {
            it[USER_NUMBER_KEY] = number
            it[USER_NAME_KEY] = name

        }
    }

    val userNumberFlow: Flow<Int> = dataStore.data.map {
        it[USER_NUMBER_KEY] ?: 0
    }

    val userNameFlow: Flow<String> = dataStore.data.map {
        it[USER_NAME_KEY] ?: ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can treat with the DataStore as a map, and check if it contains your key or not.

You need to pass your key as a paramter to the below  method, and it will return true or false based on the availibility of the key.

```
fun isKeyStored(key: Preferences.Key<String>): Flow<Boolean>  = 
    context.dataStore.data.map {
            preference -> preference.contains(key)
    }
```

Comment: .contains isn't recognized. Why is that?

Comment: I am getting this error: Required: Boolean, Found: Flow<Boolean>

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that while declaring `val USER_NAME_KEY = preferencesKey<String>("USER_NAME")` the `preferencesKey<String>` is no longer supported - in this case use `stringPreferencesKey("USER_NAME")` instead. It took me a while to verify what was going on.

In my case I also had to use `applicationContext` instead of `context`